# CSS3 transform: rotateY a div to counter the rotateY of the parent

Tags: css, 3d, rotation, css-transforms

Can I `transform: rotateY` a div to counter the `transform: rotateY` of his parent ?
**For example:**
 if I have a parent div with `rotateY(-45deg)`, all his childrens will be -45deg.
 Why can't I add `rotateY(45deg)` to the children to make it look like no rotation affected it?
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eBT4A/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add  rotateY(45deg) to the children where parent div have rotateY(-45deg), to make it look like no rotation affected it only when you set **same pivot point** to these two rotation,

in your demo example you have not apply same pivot point,

Try this...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                -webkit-perspective: 500;
            }
            #content {
                position:absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 300px; 
                height: 500px;
                background: #000;
                -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
                -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            }
            #element {
                position:absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 50px; 
                height: 50px;
                background: #f00;
                -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
                -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="element"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add preserve-3d to the parent:

```
body {
    -webkit-perspective: 500;
}
#content {
    position:fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#element {
    position:fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    background: #f00;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-45deg);
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eBT4A/10/)

As far as I know, that won't work in IE.